# Vsts VS build cant find .sln

Tags: azure-devops

Im tryng to make a CI/CD for a nuget package in VSTS, im failing on the build step, for some reason it wont find my solution file. Any idea?

[image: Folder structure]

[image: vsts]

Comment: A couple of things I see: It looks like you are trying to build a solution in your release definition - is there a reason you're doing that? Instead, you should create a build definition (pipeline) that is connected to your repo then build in that. Also, if your release definition above is tied to build artifacts, then it won't find the solution if the build isn't publishing to the release.

Comment: I don't see a task that points to the location of the source files, is it missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Vsts VS build can't find .sln

@m00nbeam360.0 pointed out the right direction.

First, the image in your question, shows you are building your project with **release pipeline** instead of **build pipeline**, which makes no sense if you want to build the solution and create the NuGet package.

You should do it with the build pipeline:

[image]

If you have some special reason to use the release pipeline to build and create NuGet package, you should make sure the artifact source type is **Azure repos Git** not **Build**:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: you were right, i was misunderstanding the build and release concepts